# How do I get the Names and Salaries of the following IDs: 264, 374, 893

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({“Employee_ID”: [192, 561, 440, 264, 112, 374, 230, 251, 893, 562],
“Name”: [“Jose”, “Kent”, “Carl”, “Mary”, “Michael”, “Cindy”, “Greg”, “John”, “Frank”, “Angela”],
“Dept”: [“Production”, “Marketing”, “Operations”, “HR”, “Finance”, “Operations”, “Marketing”, “Production”, “Finance”, “HR”],
“Phone”: [2725373, 3647364, 3184778, 1927472, 2394723, 0874872, 1018374, 2127476, 2973973, 0247462],
“Salary”: [120000, 140000, 115000, 210000, 172000, 95000, 132000, 127000, 133000, 178000]})

df

*I tried the following code to get the names and salaries of the IDs*

df[(df[“Employee_ID”] == 264) & (df[“Employee_ID”] == 374) & (df[“Employee_ID”] == 893)][[“Name”, “Salary”]]

*I was expecting to get their names and salaries*

Comment: `df.loc[df["Employee_ID"].isin([264, 374, 893]), ["Name", "Salary"]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @abokey in the comments, you can get any desired subset of your data using masking. One way of doing that is `.isin()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Employee_ID": [192, 561, 440, 264, 112, 374, 230, 251, 893, 562],
                   "Name": ["Jose", "Kent", "Carl", "Mary", "Michael", "Cindy", "Greg", "John", "Frank", "Angela"],
                    "Dept": ["Production", "Marketing", "Operations", "HR", "Finance", "Operations", "Marketing", "Production", "Finance", "HR"],
                     "Phone": [2725373, 3647364, 3184778, 1927472, 2394723, 874872, 1018374, 2127476, 2973973, 247462],
                      "Salary": [120000, 140000, 115000, 210000, 172000, 95000, 132000, 127000, 133000, 178000]})

df
```

Output:

```
    Employee_ID Name    Dept    Phone   Salary
0   192 Jose    Production  2725373 120000
1   561 Kent    Marketing   3647364 140000
2   440 Carl    Operations  3184778 115000
3   264 Mary    HR  1927472 210000
4   112 Michael Finance 2394723 172000
5   374 Cindy   Operations  874872  95000
6   230 Greg    Marketing   1018374 132000
7   251 John    Production  2127476 127000
8   893 Frank   Finance 2973973 133000
9   562 Angela  HR  247462  178000
```

---

```
get_ids = [264, 374, 893]
df = df[df["Employee_ID"].isin(get_ids)]
df = df[["Name", "Salary"]]
df
    Name    Salary
3   Mary    210000
5   Cindy   95000
8   Frank   133000
```